# Failed to install darcsden-1.1 (haskel package)

Tags: haskell

I tried to install darcsden-1.1 with

```
sudo cabal install darcsden-1.1
```

and it returns the following:

```
Failed to install hsx-0.10.4
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HJScript-0.6.1 depends on hsx-0.10.4 which failed to install.
darcs-2.8.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
darcsden-1.1 depends on hsx-0.10.4 which failed to install.
hsp-0.7.3 depends on hsx-0.10.4 which failed to install.
hsx-0.10.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please show the output of `sudo cabal install darcsden-1.1 -v3`

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ: you shouldn't use `sudo` with `cabal`. Instead, put `root-cmd: sudo` in your config file.

Comment: The error that actually matters is probably just *above* where the questioner cut off the message :)

Comment: Could you explain put root-cmd how to use it . The command sudo cabal install darcsden-1.1 -v3 gives a lot of output , a part of debug message :src/HSX/Transform.hs:987:5:
    Constructor `PTuple' should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1
    In the pattern: PTuple ps
    In a case alternative: PTuple ps -> trNpat ps PTuple (trPattern s)

Comment: In your cabal config file (which might be `~/.cabal/config`), there is a line containing the phrase `root-cmd`. This line is probably commented out. Uncomment it, and set it to `root-cmd: sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, best practice is usually not to run cabal as root - no sudo required. Also, add any error messages to your question, where they will be more easily seen. You wrote:

> I tried to install drcsden-1.1 on ubuntu 13.04 with GHC 7.6.3 with
>   sudo cabal install darcsden-1.1
>
> cabal install hsx-0.10.4 -v3 , returns a fail message , below a part
>   of the debug message.
>
> ```
> src/HSX/Transform.hs:1484:13:
>     Constructor `PTuple' should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1
>     In the pattern: PTuple ps
>     In a case alternative: PTuple ps -> concatMap gatherPVars ps
> ```

I did't see this problem when installing hsx-0.10.4 with ghc 7.6.3. So I looked at the source in question. I couldn't see where PTuple comes from, so I searched for it at Hayoo (not Hoogle, because I didn't know what package it's from.) That shows it defined in haskell-src-exts, and indeed that has been updated recently. Compare the PTuple definition in [1.13.5](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.5/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html) and [1.14.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.14.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html).

So, to work around the hsx issue: add `--constraint haskell-src-exts==1.13.5` to your cabal install command. To fix it, ask the hsx maintainer to update hsx and/or its haskell-src-exts dependency bounds.

Comment: The sudo cabal install hsx-0.10.4 --constraint hsx==1.13.5 returns the following failure message:
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
rejecting: hsx-0.10.4 (global constraint requires ==1.13.5)
rejecting: hsx-0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.7.0, 0.6.2,
...
 (global constraint requires ==0.10.4)

Comment: the cabal version is
cabal-install version 1.18.0
using version 1.18.0 of the Cabal library

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I've fixed it above.

Comment: It works. Thanks. However I still have problem with darcs-2.8.4. It returns /usr/bin/gcc returned ExitFailure 1 with error message:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
setup: Unable to link against the iconv library

Comment: I update licurl4-gnutls-dev from libcurl3-gnutls and it pass. Solved darsden-1.1 installed.